# Automatically casting RHS values for specific JOOQ columns

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have the following code, where "CI_COL" is of type citext (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html)

```
String str = "testING";

int countBad = context.fetchCount(select(Tables.MY_TABLE.CI_COL)
  .from(Tables.MY_TABLE)
  .where(Tables.MY_TABLE.CI_COL.eq(str)));

int countGood = context.fetchCount(select(Tables.MY_TABLE.CI_COL)
  .from(Tables.MY_TABLE)
  .where(Tables.MY_TABLE.CI_COL.eq(cast(str, new DefaultDataType<>(SQLDialect.POSTGRES, String.class, "citext")))));
```

The first query returns 0, and the second query correctly returns > 0.

It took me a long time to track down the root cause, because when the first query was printed (or found in the DEBUG logging), it seemed to execute in the terminal just fine.

Once I got down to the statement level and actually started binding values, that's where the root cause seemed to be. It seems to be an issue (or on purpose) in the postgres driver. This post illustrates the binding issue with citext: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAJFs0QB90bo0vWw5pZcw0c%3DLjOcOX04qPEM4nSd6uY7-T2r5hA%40mail.gmail.com

Is it possible to fix this at the JOOQ level, by having JOOQ automatically perform a cast on all right hand side values for a specific column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Side note

```
new DefaultDataType<>(...)
```

Ghasp! You're using internal API :)

#### Correct solution

The correct way to introduce new data types in jOOQ is to use a `Converter`, or in this case a data type `Binding`:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings

While most `Binding` method implementations would simply delegate to jOOQ's `DefaultBinding`, you can override the `sql()` method (which generates the bind variable's SQL string) to this:

```
@Override
public void sql(BindingSQLContext<JsonElement> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.render().sql("?::citext");
}
```